# Can I get rid of the ghosts?

Tags: rayman-legends

In the daily/weekly *Rayman Legends* challenges, you race against "ghosts" of other players.  I find these *very* distracting and most of the time have a hard time distinguishing between my player and the other ghosts.  **How do I get rid of those ghosts?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pause the game and go to the menu (using the <kbd>+</kbd> button on the Wii U, I am unsure about other platforms) there's an option for **Ghosts** with three settings: **All**, **Friends Only**, and **None**.

Personally I find Friends Only better than All. But I have no friends `:-(` so all I see is ghosts of *my own prior attempts* which I find far less distracting than ghosts of other players (especially when they play as other characters). You'll obviously want **None** to disable the ghosts completely.

On a side not I find that the ghosts distract me much more on distance challenges where you're racing against the flames and you have to go as far as you can. On time challenges where you need to collect as many *Lums* as you can I actually find that the ghosts help me a lot.

Here's what it looks like on the Wii U. I'm not sure about what other platforms would look like:

[image]

Comment: I'm on the PS3.  I'll try pausing and see if I can find the menu option.

Comment: Check the screen capture I just posted, does that help at all? I know it'll be different because this is from a Wii U but I don't have a PS3 to test with.

Comment: Confirmed. Took a break from the game. In finally back into it and was able to turn off ghosts. Thanks.